# When is $\det (X+Y) = \det X + \det Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $X$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $Y$ an $n\times n$ matrix. Are there conditions which forces $\det (X+Y) = \det X + \det Y$. Any comments, references are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h265916). Found using Approach0.

Comment: The equality is trivial when $X+Y$, $X$ and $Y$ are singular.

Comment: This is a hypersurface of degree $n-1$ in the entries of $Y$: $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\operatorname{Tr}[(\operatorname{adj} X)^{(m)}Y^{(m)}]=0$ where $M^{(m)}$ is the matrix of $m\times m$-cofactors of the a matrix $M$, and $\operatorname{adj} M$ is the adjugate matrix of $M$.  That is possibly the most general description without knowing more about $X$, $n$ or the field you are working with.

Comment: @user10354138 How do you derive this equation? (Maybe you could explain as an answer?) Also I am interested in this question over the reals.